# Dart: How to call 2D Lists?

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

For example we have a list like this:

```
List<String> _persons = ['Ian' : '1', 'Dave' : '2' , 'Jenny' : '3' ];
```

How can we map this List like below:

```
_persons.map((element) => Card:(
     Text(element)
  )
).toList()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that like below code.

```
List _persons = [
                  {'name': 'lan', 'value': '1'},
                  {'name': 'Dave', 'value': '2'},
                  {'name': 'Jenny', 'value': '3'}
                ];

                _persons.map((element) {
                  print(element['name']+" : "+ element['value']);
                  showDialog(
                      context: context,
                      builder: (BuildContext context) {
                        return AlertDialog(
                          content: Text(element['name']+" : "+element['value']),
                        );
                      });
                }).toList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code snap which you can follow and implement that to do the thing.

```
List<Map<String, String> _persons = [{'Ian': '1'}, {'Dave': '2'}, {'Jenny': '3'}];

_persons.map((element) => Text('${element.key}: ${element.value}')).toList();
```